# Retrieve a subdocument from Mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have no code to show as I do not know how to achieve what I want.

I have read that it is possible to return a sub document from a document, but I have not found out how to actually do this. A contrived example of a Users collection:

```
[
   {
      "_id":0,
      "Name":"Person 1",
      "Cupboard":[
         {
            "_id":0,
            "Items":[
               {
                  "_id":1,
                  "Name":"item 1"
               },
               {
                  "_id":2,
                  "Name":"item 2"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
    ,
    {
      "_id":1,
      "Name":"Person 2",
      "Cupboard":[
         {
            "_id":0,
            "Items":[
               {
                  "_id":1,
                  "Name":"item 1"
               },
               {
                  "_id":2,
                  "Name":"item 2"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How do I ONLY return Items from a cupboard, assuming I know the cupboard's _id? I am using the C# driver, but even help doing it in the mongo shell would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is [project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#result-projections) only the fields that you want. So on your dataset, return only items from cupboard will be:

```
db.collection.find({ ... }, { 'Cupboard.Items' : 1, _id : 0 })
```

Comment: Would this not return an array of docs only projecting the `Cupboard.Items` array?

Comment: While this returns the parent document minus fields, so not technically only returning items, I'm inclined to mark this as the answer as I simply don't understand $unwind/$project in the answer below...

Comment: @SamDelaney try `db.Users.aggregate({$unwind: "$Cupboard"},{$unwind:"$Cupboard.Items"},{$project :{ _id:"$Cupboard.Items._id",Name:"$Cupboard.Items.Name"}})` this will unwind the nested item array and project an array of documents matching the `Items` sub documents

Comment: Let me know if you want to give the Aggregation command a try and i'll help the C#

Comment: `$unwind` is super simple .. it just explodes your array. Let us know if you choose for AF.

Comment: sambomartin & miguel - I'd like to do this the correct way, so if you can help me figure out the C# for this I'd appreciate it. If it's in its own answer I can mark as right answer.

Comment: @sambomartin ideally both so I can understand $unwind better, but the find primarily, as I can still retrieve an instance of the top level class and pick out the bit that is returned in the query.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return many `Items` you can use the aggregation framework's `$unwind` to project the child items as the result of the query.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/

Then use `$project` to return the results of the `Items`

Make sure you filter results early in the pipeline using `$match` operator to make use of indexes.

You can create a pipeline as a BsonDocument.  Here's an example:

```
var match = new BsonDocument 
            { 
                { 
                    "$match", 
                    new BsonDocument 
                        { 
                            {"Cupboard.Items._id", 123} 
                        } 
                } 
            };

var match2 = new BsonDocument 
            { 
                /* other pipeline op */
            };

var pipeline = new[] { match, match2 };
var result = coll.Aggregate(pipeline);
```

If however you want to return the `User` documents (or part of) where a child `Item` matches specific criteria you can simple use find.

`db.Users.find({'Cupboard.Items._id':1234})`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
> db.users.find({"Cupboard._id": 0}, {"Cupboard.$" : 1}).pretty()
```

Which will return

```
{
        "_id" : 0,
        "Cupboard" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "Items" : [
                                {
                                        "_id" : 1,
                                        "Name" : "item 1"
                                },
                                {
                                        "_id" : 2,
                                        "Name" : "item 2"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "Cupboard" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "Items" : [
                                {
                                        "_id" : 1,
                                        "Name" : "item 1"
                                },
                                {
                                        "_id" : 2,
                                        "Name" : "item 2"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
>
```

However lets change our documents around so that we have the following, so that our users ahve multiple cupboards and some diffrent items in them too

```
> db.users.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : 0,
        "Name" : "Person 1",
        "Cupboard" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "Items" : [
                                {
                                        "_id" : 1,
                                        "Name" : "item 1"
                                },
                                {
                                        "_id" : 2,
                                        "Name" : "item 2"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "Items" : [
                                {
                                        "_id" : 1,
                                        "Name" : "item 1"
                                },
                                {
                                        "_id" : 2,
                                        "Name" : "item 2"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "Name" : "Person 2",
        "Cupboard" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "Items" : [
                                {
                                        "_id" : 1,
                                        "Name" : "item 1"
                                },
                                {
                                        "_id" : 2,
                                        "Name" : "item 2"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "Items" : [
                                {
                                        "_id" : 21,
                                        "Name" : "item 1"
                                },
                                {
                                        "_id" : 22,
                                        "Name" : "item 2"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

We can now list all cupboards by user.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$match: {"Cupboard._id": 0}},
    {$project: {"Cupboard._id": 1}}
])

{ "_id" : 0, "Cupboard" : [ { "_id" : 0 }, { "_id" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "Cupboard" : [ { "_id" : 0 }, { "_id" : 2 } ] }
```